# Why does my code return multiple echo strings

Tags: php, oop

Whenever I submit my form, it returns three times "Good" as "GoodGoodGood" and I'm trying to figure out why. The ony thing I know, that it has to do something with Arrays.

`check.php` checks if all 3 inputs are not empty, if everthing is fine it echo'es "Good".

```
class Check {
    public function mty() {
        global $required;
        global $field;

        foreach($required as $field) {
            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                //Code...
            } else {
                echo "Good";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`submit.php`

```
$check = new Check;

//Gets names of inputs
$required = array('name', 'price', 'id');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $check->mty();
}
```

I'm new to OOP, just want to find a fix for the problem. Is there anything I can improve in this code?

Comment: you see that `echo` inside that `foreach` loop .. ?

Comment: GLOBAL is nasty, specially in objects. Pass the required data as parameters to the method instead

Comment: **Also** Did you really mean to code `global $field;`?? Thats a variable created in the foreach loop.

Comment: @treyBake How do I end the loop before `else` statement?

Comment: Thats not the question! You have to do all 3 loops to check all 3 fields exist

Comment: @Berisko build an array and echo once.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is used `global` so I can define the variable outside the class in another file.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter. I am guessing you dont quite understand what GLOBAL means in PHP either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're echoing "good" on each iteration in your loop.

You can create a variable that hold the state and check that and echo after the loop instead:

```
// The variable that keeps the state
$success = true;

foreach($required as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        // Set the state as false
        $success = false;
    }
}

// If state is true, no value was empty and we echo 'Good'... once.
if ($success) {
    echo 'Good';
}
```

As others have mentioned, using `global` should be avoided when ever possible (which is always if you're structure is sound).

There's also the issue of you using `global $field;` while using `$field` in your `foreach` loop as well. If you're planing to use `$field` you've imported using `global $field;` in that method, you should use another name in your `foreach`. If you're not planing on using it, remove `global $field;`.

Comment: Thanks this tottaly works, thanks for commenting each line. But is there any other way using variables from another file?

Comment: You can pass the variables when you call the method. Define the method like: `public function mty(array $required) { ... }` and then just pass that variable when calling the method: `$check->mty($required);`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the `array_filter()` to get only non-empty values and compare the count of that against the original `$_POST` count

```
<?php
    # pretend like this was what was posted
    $posted = [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'bar' => 'foo',
        'treybake' => 'is awesome?'
    ];

    # your GLOBALS
    $required = ['foo', 'treybake'];

    # compare the count of the array without any empty elements 
    # vs original post count
    if (count(array_filter($posted, function($el){return (!empty($el));})) === count($posted)) {
        echo 'good';
    } else {
        echo 'something bad';
    }
```